# How to create table in mdb from dbf query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, dbf

I have a dbf that I would like to copy into a new mdb using VB6.

The following is where I am up to, I can create the new mdb easily enough, however, I thought I could just do a Select query with an INTO to create a new table with the data.

Please note: what I'm assuming is the MSAccess table gets created at the time the sql query gets run.

I get a syntax error in FROM clause. What I was trying to do is manipulate this sql query to do what I need it to:

> sql = "INSERT INTO [Table1] SELECT * FROM [source.dbf] IN " & dbfPath

My example vb:

```
new_mdb = root_directory & "\Temp\LnX.mdb"

Dim conCatalog As ADOX.Catalog
Set conCatalog = New ADOX.Catalog
conCatalog.Create "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & new_mdb
Set conCatalog = Nothing

Dim db As Database
Dim sql As String
Dim dbfPath As String

Set db = OpenDatabase(new_mdb, dbDriverComplete, False)
dbfPath = "'" & root_directory & "\Core'[dBase IV;]"

sql = "SELECT * FROM [LnX.dbf] IN '" & dbfPath & "' INTO [LnX]"
db.Execute sql

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you do that with Access itself? If not I am guessing you cannot do it using ADO.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if you meant just do an import via access gui or do an import via vb, however I didn't want either. A user may not have access available so I've avoided the access application object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with a ADODB connection to the newly created mdb. Then executed this to create the table and data.

```
sql = "SELECT * INTO [" & table_name & "] " & _
      "FROM [dBase IV;DATABASE=" & sourceDBpath & "].[" & table_name & "]"
```